# Как в jquery выбрать первый следующий сиблинг определенного элемента?

Tags: jquery

Допустим такая структура:

```
<img src="#" alt="">
<span>
    <strong>
    </strong>
</span>
<div>первый див</div>
<div>еще див</div>
```

Код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
        // как здесь выбрать первый элемент div, идущий после этого img?
    });
};
<script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').click(function(){
        var first_div = $(this).nextAll('div')[0];
    });
});
```

Comment: как все просто :) Спасибо :)

Comment: Пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Исправил:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
        $(this).next().next('div').бла-бла-бла();
    });
});
```

Практически то же, что я сперва указывал - лишь с минимальными изменениями :)

Comment: Советую к прочтению http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/jquery/51717/

Comment: мда, уж ... действительно, читаем документацию по селекторам :) Этот код работать не будет. Читаем описание next(): "Get the <b><i>immediately</i></b> following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements ..." (http://api.jquery.com/next/). Между img и div стоит span - поэтому и не будет работать.
Да и вопрос был вообще другой. Надо выбрать следующий за img первый див именно в обработчике события этого img, т.е. через this.

Comment: Да, что-то я напутал... Извиняюсь) Сейчас что-нибудь придумаем ;)

Comment: $(this).next().next('div').бла-бла-бла(); Это решение для частного случая. Я точно также могу взять nextAll(), а потом второй элемент по порядку. Еще раз: вопрос как отобрать "следующий за img первый div". Естественно, что между img и div может быть не только один span, как в этом частном примере, а сколько угодно сиблингов или не быть их вообще. Вот что я не знаю как сделать красиво :)

Comment: Так бы и указали в вопросе, что может быть куча чего-то другого :) На досуге поковыряюсь...

Comment: оно и понятно, что нужно решение для общего случая. Конкретно с этим примером проблем нет.